# How to avoid coalesce for duplicate tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have the following database structure:

**tblShelter**
ShelterId
PetId
ClientId
ShelterName
Address

**tblClient**
ClientId
PetId

**tblPet**
PetId
PetName

So, Pet can belong to a shelter or to a registered shelter client (adopted pet).

So my Shelter table has data as follows:

```
ShelterId  PetId ClientId ShelterName 
    1       100    NULL       Test
    1       NULL   101        Test   
    1       102    NULL       Test
```

So, I need to get all PetNames for each shelter (Direct shelter pets or clients)

Here's my query:

```
Select Coalesce(p.PetName, pclient.PetName) as PetName 
from tblShelter s
Left Join tblPet p
on p.PetId = s.PetId   
Left Join (select p2.PetId, p2.PetName 
           from tblClient c 
           join tblPet p2 
           on c.PetId = p2.PetId) pclient 
on s.PetId = pclient.PetId
where shelterId=1
```

Question: Is it possible to optimize this query? Currently, it doesn't look pretty. Please note that database structure is shown for simplicity. Unfortunately, it cannot be modified. Is it possible to get rid of coalesce in a smart way or get rid of sub query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - change your `JOIN` order:

```
Select p.PetName 
from tblShelter s
Left Join tblClient c
    on s.ClientId = c.ClientId
inner join tblPet p
    on p.PetId = s.PetId or
       p.PetId = c.PetId
where shelterId=1
```

`JOIN`s aren't strictly based on joining two tables - the `ON` clauses can reference any table that has already been joined to form either side of the current join. So here, we allow the join to `tblPet` to be based on either the direct reference (via `s.PetId`) or via the optionally joined in `tblClient`.

Of course, you can further simplify the above query by making a smarter `ON` condition for the join to `tblPet` - but the way to do that would be to reintroduce the feature you're seeking to avoid - `COALESCE`. I've no idea what your reasons are for seeking to avoid that feature though.

Comment: Hi Damien, thank you for your reply. I'm not seeking to remove COALESCE per se. Just want to simplify my query and make it as efficient as possible. Can you explain on how to achieve a smarter "on" condition?

Comment: @user194076 - `p.PetId = COALESCE(s.Petid,c.PetId)`

Comment: Awesome! Let me try this on my query

Comment: Damien, thanks for your suggestion. Your solution works great, but for some reason it is slower than the orinigal query in my case. I cannot extract a reproducible example at this time, but will probably post another question soon. Thanks!